# How to pass in async function to receive values within function class

Tags: c#, automapper, func

I have a group of functions that I would like to pass to another function to execute within that function.
Below is what I attempted. The final one is the one I am trying to use with the generic function.

My controller function

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<Client> CreateClient([FromBody] Client client)
{
    return GetMap(client, _clientRepo.AddAsync);
}
```

Mapper function

```
public static Task<Client> GetMap(Client client, Func<Data.Models.Client, Client> func)
{
   var map = Mapper.Map<Client, Data.Models.Client>(client);
   var ret = func(map);
   return Mapper.Map<Data.Models.Client, Client>(ret);
}
```

Working function

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<Client> CreateClient([FromBody] Client client)
{
    var map = Mapper.Map<Client, Data.Models.Client>(client);
    var ret = await _clientRepo.AddAsync(map);
    return Mapper.Map<Data.Models.Client, Client>(ret);
}
```

Comment: What does the other function look like? It looks like you just want it to take a `Func<Client, Task<Client>>` parameter?

Answer (score 0):

An async function cannot return `Data.Models.Client` it can only return `Task<IData.Models.Client>` `Task` or `void`.

you should get `Func<Task<Data.Models.Client>, Client>` as a parameter

If you want to target an async implementation and a non-async implementation I would create two overloads for your method, an async one and a non-async one.

```
public static async Task<Client> GetMap(Client client, Func<Task<Data.Models.Client>, Client> func)
{
    var map = Mapper.Map<Client, Data.Models.Client>(client);
    var ret = await func(map);
    return Mapper.Map<Data.Models.Client, Client>(ret);
}

public static Task<Client> GetMap(Client client, Func<Data.Models.Client>, Client> func)
{
    var map = Mapper.Map<Client, Data.Models.Client>(client);
    var ret = func(map);
    return Mapper.Map<Data.Models.Client, Client>(ret);
}
```

Comment: I am not sure if `Mapper.Map<>()` returns a task, but I am assuming it does since it is your return type